# How can I make VS Code remember the sidebar width on a per-workspace basis?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code remember the last size of the sidebar. When I'm working on project "A", I close it, then open project "B", resize the sidebar, close project "B" and go back to project "A", I get in it the size of the sidebar from the "B" project.

I expect to save in workspace settings a width of the sidebar for my every project. Ideally there should be something like "workbench.sideBar.width" but there isn't.

Is there any way to save sidebar width in workspace settings?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. I have looked extensively for this.

[I made a suggestion for this behavior in the VSCode repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158603), and if it gets 20 thumbs up, it will be added to their backlog.

Update: It has ben added to their backlog!

Answer (score 1):

There are two different families of proposals for how to implement this in VS Code- both having feature requests that I'd suggest that you take your pick of and give a thumbs up to. You can also subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

- [Sidebar defaultWidth, View-Specific Sidebar widths, & View-Specific Sidebar defaultWidths #158603](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158603), which requests that there be *settings* which can be set on a per-workspace-basis that control the default widths of each item of the primary sidebar.
- [Save width of Explorer column (sidebar) in Workspace #75017](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75017), which requests that the with be remembered *without* having to specify it via a setting. Behind the scenes, this would probably mean storing the width in the `.../Code/User/workspaceStorage/<workspace-hash>/state.vscdb` database file for the workspace.

The main consideration I would make for whether or not you think a setting is the better decision is whether you think *everyone* working on the project will agree on what the width should be. Remember- the whole point of the question here is to have the width be persisted/set on a per-workspace-basis. I.e. either you need to store it in `./.vscode/settings.json`- which if tracked in version control, will be shared by *everyone*, or you require everyone who cares about this to do it on a personal basis by creating a `.code-workspace` wrapper, putting their setting in the workspace file's `settings` property.

For that reason, I personally think the non-setting approach is better.